# Input field conditions for beam gaussian propagation

Tags: optics, laser, fourier-transform, simulations

I am trying to calculate a beam propagating through a lens with focal length $f_0$ and a gaussian shape perpendicular to the beam propagation axis. For that I use the equation
$$\partial_zE=\frac{i}{2k_0}\nabla^2_\perp E$$
and solve it either using the fourier transformation (in the cartesian system) or using a fast hankel transform (in the cylindrical coordinate system).
Now, based on my understanding, I can either define my input for a beam radius of $r_0$ and a propagation constant $k_0$ as (here for the cylindrical case)
$$E(r, 0) = E_0\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{r_0^2}\right)\cdot\exp\left(i\cdot k_0\cdot\frac{r^2}{2f_0}\right)$$
or I use the solution for the paraxial case, describing the complex field of the gaussian beam
$$E(r, z) = E_0\frac{w_0}{w(z)}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{w^2(z)}\right)\exp\left(i\left[k_0z-\arctan\left(\frac{z}{z_r}\right)+\frac{k_0r^2}{2R(z)}\right]\right)$$
with $w_0$ the minimal radius at the focal spot, $w(z)$ the beam diameter at position $z$, $z_r$ the rayleigh length and $R(z)$ the curvature of the wave front. To correctly use this definition, I have to use the field calculated at $E(r, -f_0)$.

I propagate both $E$-field using the method described above, but while both result in a peak at the focal spot, I am not sure which of both is representing the situation more accurate, and when I should choose which over the other?